# Identifying "Must not connect point more than one line feature" errors in electrical network?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, topology

[image]

I have attached an example image to show the problem: This is electrical network data single service point to connect more than one Service pole. Is it available any topology rules?
I would like some suggestions regarding this error .

Answer (score 2):

Not any directly related topology rule I am aware of, but something simple is to do a spatial join which should result in 1 line per service point for your 'normal' case, anything else is an error.  You may benefit from running a summary or frequency check on points to see how many lines joined per point.
Other than that, since this is a utility network, won't this type of error also be flagged as a loop?